# Set Password adn read only for downloading files(*.xml) using javascript or any client side

Tags: javascript

I want to download the file using JavaScript and it should be password protected and readonly.

Here is my sample code:

```
const blob = new Blob([data.dados], { type: 'xml;charset=utf-8' });

saveAs(blob, `${filename}.xml`);
```

Comment: You can't do this client side only.

Comment: Thanks @NNL993. But is there any way to do this in like angular, node js etc..

Comment: I don't think there is any safe way (expect one-time password) to keep in safe files, you may try to do this using Nuxt or some kind of these technologies(SSR) to generate one-time password, but I had no idea how to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

As NNL993 said in the comments, password protected files should be served from the backend, not the frontend.

You can use OTP but those would also be generated from a backend and validated from a backend.

You can put a password layer in the frontend but it would be very simple to get around that if you don't consistently protect your page / files with a backend control that checks whether the user can or cannot download the file.

If you still want to go the front end way, which is the NON SECURE way, you can add a page or component that takes a password input and shows the download button of the file if the password control, still in the frontend, passes.
You should know that everything about this happens in the frontend and the only layer you can add is that of obfuscation (minification of code) but that's not enough.